# .Net 7 - Null Conditional-Access Operator (?. or ?[]) Rules in Boolean Evaluations

Tags: c#, .net, operators

I was wondering if someone has a documentation source or a good explanation for the exact rules/implementation of the interactions between a boolean-resulting operation and the null conditional-access operators (.? and ?[]). I use them all the time and they usually do what I want them to do, but sometimes they act in a "funny" way that I can't seem to fully understand. When I break down the code it both makes sense and doesn't make sense at the same time. Here's an example:

```
            string str = null;

            if (str?.Length != 0) //evaluates to true - str is null, therefore Length is null(able?) and is a value other than zero
            {
                Console.WriteLine("True");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False");
            }            

            if (str?.Length > 0) //evaluates to false - str is null, therefore Length is null(able?) and null is not greater than zero
            {
                Console.WriteLine("True");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False");
            }
```

However, the logical equivalent to the first example evaluates to false, as I would expect it to:

```
            string str = null;

            //However, the 'equivalent' logic evaluates to false. 
            if (str != null && str.Length != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("True");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False");
            }
```

**So, under the hood, what is going on exactly that creates different behaviors for essentially logically equivalent code?** I would expect the short-circuiting of str?. to return false when being evaluated for a boolean since everything after the ? is 'invalid' due to being associated with a null reference, but this isn't the case. Or are the code examples **NOT** logically equivalent because I'm missing/not understanding something?

I imagine .Net is doing something to turn '0' and 'Length' into a nullable ints and is doing some interplay between them, but I can't actually re-create code using nullable ints that reproduces the results of

```
            if (str?.Length != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("True");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("False");
            }
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on? I've had to squash a few silly bugs related to the misuse of '?' that I would like to avoid in the future.

I've already looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators and it doesn't seem to address the details of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have looked at Nullable value types (C# reference), under [Lifted Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators), where you would see the following paragraph:

> For the comparison operators <, >, <=, and >=, if one or both operands are null, the result is false; otherwise, the contained values of operands are compared. Do not assume that because a particular comparison (for example, <=) returns false, the opposite comparison (>) returns true.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly how you wrote it. `Null-conditional` operator **is not shortcut for returning `false`** whenever operation evaluates to null. It just prevents you from accessing property when object is null.

If you will extract your `str?.Length` to variable like this: `var count = str?.Length;` you will see that `count` is null.

So what you are doing is:

```cs
if (null != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("True");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("False");
}
```

This evaluates to `true`. If you wan't to get results as you expected, you should also use `null-coalescing` operator, like this:

```cs
int valueIfNull = -1;

if ((str?.Length ?? valueIfNull) != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("True");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("False");
}
```

If you wan't to know what is generated by compiler, check [this](https://sharplab.io/) website.
For example:
`str?.Length != 0;` is compiled to `text == null || text.Length != 0;` while `str?.Length > 0` is compiled to `text != null && text.Length > 0`